Selecting between SN2 and E2 primary alkyl halide
This might be a meaningless question, but I just want the ideas and opinions of my fellow stackexchangeiers.
The question is that, does a primary alkyl halide undergo SN2 or E2 with a strong $unhindered$ base at $high$ temperatures?
I am aware that at $low$ temperatures, even $hindered$ bases like tert-butoxide undergo SN2. So, I guess that due to the high preference for SN2, unhindered bases would do SN2 at higher temperatures also.

Heat favors elimination reactions. You can think of this two ways: entropy increases in an E2, which increases the $T\Delta S$ term in the Gibbs free energy—increasing the temperature only makes this term even bigger so it contributes a greater fraction to deciding the $\Delta G$ of the process; and the other way to think about it is that the activation energy for an E2 (to reach the transition state) is higher than for an SN2. Increasing the temperature means more particles have enough energy for the E2 to be a viable reaction route.

It may well depend on the electronic and steric effects governing the specific molecule, such as whether you stand to gain conjugation but generally, the heat would favour the elimination as it guides the T*deltaS term towards thermodynamic favourability because the entropic factor inevitably prefers the elimination. Additionally the elimination gets kinetically favoured by the temperature as the thermal energy facilitates more molecules overcoming the activation energy barrier.
